# How do I make a property public get but private set in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I just stumbled over this in some C# code...:

```
public Foo     Foo    { get; private set; }
```

How can I do the same thing in vb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course (smacks forehead)...:

```
Public Property Foo() As Foo
    Get
        ...
    End Get
    Private Set(ByVal value As Foo)
        ...
    End Set
End Property
```

I did not think about putting the private keyword down there...

Comment: As @em70 alluded to in his answer, note that this isn't quite the same thing. Get/Set with different access levels in VB.NET only works with a backing field, whereas the C# version doesn't need a backing field, see [Property Definitions That Require Standard Syntax on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx#Anchor_2)

Answer (score 4):

VB.NET does not have automatic properties like C# 3.0 does. In VB the equivalent would be:

```
    Private _Foo As SomeType
    Public Property Foo() As SomeType
        Get
            Return _Foo
        End Get
        Private Set(ByVal value As SomeType)
            _Foo = value
        End Set
    End Property
```